# AKS PersistentVolume Affinity?

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod, persistent-volumes

Disclaimer: This question is very specific about the used platforms and the UseCase we are trying to solve with it. Also it compares two approaches we currently use at least in a development stage and are trying to compare, but perhaps don't fully understand yet. I am asking for guidance on this very specific topic...

**A)** We are running a Kafka cluster as Kafka Tasks on DC/OS, where persistence of data is maintained via local Disk Storage which is provisioned on the very same host as the according kafka broker instance.

**B)** We are trying to run Kafka on Kubernetes (via Strimzi Operator), specifically Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) and are struggling to get reliable Data Persistence using the StorageClasses you get in AKS. We tried three possibilities:

1. (Default) Azure Disk
2. Azure File
3. emptyDir

I see two major issues with Azure Disk, as we are able to set the Kafka Pod Affinity in a manner that they do not end up on the same maintenance zone / host, we have no instrument to bind the according PersistentVolume anywhere near the Pod. There is nothing like NodeAffinity for AzureDisks. Also it is fairly common that an Azure Disk ends up on another host than its corresponding pod, which might be limited by network bandwidth then?

With Azure File we don't have issues because of maintenance zones which are going down temporarily, but as a high latency storage option it doesn't seem to be a good fit and also Kafka has trouble to delete / update files on retention.

So I ended up using an ephemeral Storage Cluster which is commonly NOT recommended but doesn't come with the problems above. The Volume "lives" near the pod and is available to it as long as the pod itself runs on any node. In the maintenance case pod AND volume die together. As long as I am able to maintain a quorum, I don't see where this might cause issues.

- Is there anything like podAffinity for PersistentVolumes as Azure-Disk is per definition Node bound?
- What are the major downsides in using emptyDir for persistence in a Kafka Cluster on Kubernetes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything like podAffinity for PersistentVolumes as Azure-Disk
> is per definition Node bound?

As I know, there is nothing like podaffinity for PersistentVolumes as Azure-Disk. The azure disk should be attached to the node, so if the pod changes the host node, then the pod can't use the volume on that disk. Only the Azure file share is podAffinity.

> What are the major downsides in using emptyDir for persistence in a
> Kafka Cluster on Kubernetes?

You can take a look at the [emptyDir](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir):

> scratch space, such as for a disk-based merge sort

This is the most thing you need to watch out for when you use the AKS. You need to calculate the disk space, perhaps you need to attach multiple Azure disks to the nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm afraid thats not completely right... Its fairly common that a pod in aks gets an azure-disk which is attached to a.completely different host node....thats why we came in trouble when a zone (where the disk was) went down for maintenance while the pod was still alive, but without disk. I am wondering if that is the intended way this should work?

Comment: @JürgenZornig The availability zone is a feature to keep the VM work from the disaster. When you the managed disk as the volume, it does not use the availability zone. So the node will recovery, but the disk won't. That's the reason the pod is still alive but without the disk. And you can't control the availability zone. So it's useless for your purpose.

Comment: Yes, thats what we also found out using azure-disk as kafka storage backend. So it seems there is no better solution to this than to stick with `emptyDir` StorageClass and never run out of enough kafka replicas

Comment: @JürgenZornig Yes, at least what I know is.

Comment: @JürgenZornig Any more updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Well, it doesn't really solve our problem but when that is the situation on this platform, I'll accept that as an answer. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Starting off - I'm not sure what you mean about an Azure Disk ending up on a node other than where the pod is assigned - that shouldn't be possible, per my understanding (for completeness, you can do this on a VM with the [shared disks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/disks-shared-enable) feature outside of AKS, but as far as I'm aware that's not supported in AKS for dynamic disks at the time of writing). If you're looking at the `volume.kubernetes.io/selected-node` annotation on the PVC, I don't believe that's updated after initial creation.

You can reach the configuration you're looking for by using a statefulset with antiaffinity. Consider [this statefulset](https://gist.github.com/phealy/801ac1f5f5a3fac4b32ff580a72eea20). It creates three pods, which must be in different availability zones. I'm deploying this to an AKS cluster with a nodepool (nodepool2) with two nodes per AZ:

```
❯ kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{","}{.metadata.labels.topology\.kubernetes\.io\/zone}{"\n"}{end}'
aks-nodepool1-25997496-vmss000000,0
aks-nodepool2-25997496-vmss000000,westus2-1
aks-nodepool2-25997496-vmss000001,westus2-2
aks-nodepool2-25997496-vmss000002,westus2-3
aks-nodepool2-25997496-vmss000003,westus2-1
aks-nodepool2-25997496-vmss000004,westus2-2
aks-nodepool2-25997496-vmss000005,westus2-3
```

Once the statefulset is deployed and spun up, you can see each pod was assigned to one of the nodepool2 nodes:

```
❯ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP             NODE                                NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
echo-0   1/1     Running   0          3m42s   10.48.36.102   aks-nodepool2-25997496-vmss000001   <none>           <none>
echo-1   1/1     Running   0          3m19s   10.48.36.135   aks-nodepool2-25997496-vmss000002   <none>           <none>
echo-2   1/1     Running   0          2m55s   10.48.36.72    aks-nodepool2-25997496-vmss000000   <none>           <none>
```

Each pod created a PVC based on the template:

```
❯ kubectl get pvc
NAME          STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS      AGE
demo-echo-0   Bound    pvc-bf6104e0-c05e-43d4-9ec5-fae425998f9d   1Gi        RWO            managed-premium   25m
demo-echo-1   Bound    pvc-9d9fbd5f-617a-4582-abc3-ca34b1b178e4   1Gi        RWO            managed-premium   25m
demo-echo-2   Bound    pvc-d914a745-688f-493b-9b82-21598d4335ca   1Gi        RWO            managed-premium   24m
```

Let's take a look at one of the PVs that was created:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  annotations:
    pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: "yes"
    pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: kubernetes.io/azure-disk
    volumehelper.VolumeDynamicallyCreatedByKey: azure-disk-dynamic-provisioner
  creationTimestamp: "2021-04-05T14:08:12Z"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pv-protection
  labels:
    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region: westus2
    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone: westus2-3
  name: pvc-9d9fbd5f-617a-4582-abc3-ca34b1b178e4
  resourceVersion: "19275047"
  uid: 945ad69a-92cc-4d8d-96f4-bdf0b80f9965
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  azureDisk:
    cachingMode: ReadOnly
    diskName: kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-9d9fbd5f-617a-4582-abc3-ca34b1b178e4
    diskURI: /subscriptions/02a062c5-366a-4984-9788-d9241055dda2/resourceGroups/rg-sandbox-aks-mc-sandbox0-westus2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-9d9fbd5f-617a-4582-abc3-ca34b1b178e4
    fsType: ""
    kind: Managed
    readOnly: false
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  claimRef:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    name: demo-echo-1
    namespace: zonetest
    resourceVersion: "19275017"
    uid: 9d9fbd5f-617a-4582-abc3-ca34b1b178e4
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region
          operator: In
          values:
          - westus2
        - key: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
          operator: In
          values:
          - westus2-3
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: managed-premium
  volumeMode: Filesystem
status:
  phase: Bound
```

As you can see, that PV has a required `nodeAffinity` for nodes in `failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone` with value `westus2-3`. This ensures that the pod that owns that PV will only ever get placed on a node in `westus2-3`, and that PV will be bound to the node the disk is running on when the pod is started.

At this point, I deleted all the pods to get them on the other nodes:

```
❯ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP             NODE                                NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
echo-0   1/1     Running   0          4m4s    10.48.36.168   aks-nodepool2-25997496-vmss000004   <none>           <none>
echo-1   1/1     Running   0          3m30s   10.48.36.202   aks-nodepool2-25997496-vmss000005   <none>           <none>
echo-2   1/1     Running   0          2m56s   10.48.36.42    aks-nodepool2-25997496-vmss000003   <none>           <none>
```

There's no way to see it via Kubernetes, but you can see via the Azure portal that managed disk `kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-bf6104e0-c05e-43d4-9ec5-fae425998f9d`, which backs pv `pvc-bf6104e0-c05e-43d4-9ec5-fae425998f9d`, which backs PVC `zonetest/demo-echo-0`, is listed as `Managed by: aks-nodepool2-25997496-vmss_4`, so it's been removed and assigned to the node where the pod is running.

[Portal screenshot showing disk attached to node 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOI6m.png)

If I were to remove nodes such that I didn't have nodes in AZ 3, I wouldn't be able to start pod `echo-1`, since it's bound to a disk in AZ 3, which can't be attached to a node not in AZ 3.